# JQuery doesn`t fire/work with my Rails 3.2 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

As in the title, I`ve made sure all needed JS files are included in the meta tags, included the jquery-rails/coffee-rails gem, linked to a external one just in case.

This is a modified script from Ryan Bates tutorial on Stripe, from what I understand it`s suppose to fire up by detecting the submit action from the form.

Since I'm not that familiar with JS or CoffeeScript, I can't really pin point what's the problem here.

Would appreciate any help I can get.

**The donations.js file:**

```
jQuery ->
      Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
      donation.setupForm()

donation =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_donation').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        donation.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
      card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, donation.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
```

**The donations/new.html.erb form**

```
<%= form_for(@donation) do |f| %>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :from %>
                    <%= f.text_field :from %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, :name => nil %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code (CVV)" %>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, :name => nil %>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
                  <%= select_month nil, {:add_month_numbers => true}, {:name => nil, :id => "card_month"} %>
                  <%= select_year nil, {:start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year+15}, {:name => nil, :id => "card_year"} %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :Notes %>
                    <%= f.text_field :note %>
                </div>
                <br>
                <center>
                    <span class="BigBold">Amount: $2.50</span>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :amount, {:value => "2,5" } %><br>
                </center>
                <br>
                <center>
                    <%= f.submit "Donate Now", :class => 'donate-button' %>
                </center>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript seems to be, well, *Coffeescript* - make sure it's put in its own `donations.js.coffee` file, and that you're including the `coffee-rails` gem while you're at it.

Standard debugging techniques would be useful here - try adding an `alert("It lives!")` or something after the initial `jQuery ->` line to see if the document.ready handler is ever being called.

If not, check to make sure that the `donations.js.coffee` file is being loaded in the first place, and if not, make sure you're either loading it in your page's header, or you have something like this in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require donations
```

Or, if you just want to include everything in `app/assets/javascripts`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter, I have coffee-rails included in gemfile. When I posted the I forgot to delete the alert () before the processCard: part.

Comment: Also, here's the source that I`m using https://github.com/railscasts/episode-288/blob/master/saas-after/app/assets/javascripts/subscriptions.js.coffee

Answer (score 0):

Peter is correct, your coffeescript code should be properly named so that it can be translated to JavaScript.

An additional debugging strategy is to look at the html/js source being sent to your browser.  Use the view source command to see the html source. Then click on the reference to the js link containing the translated donations.js.